# Finding end of char pointer, int and float

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers, systems-programming

I have a function that will be passed a void pointer. This pointer can either be an int, char, or float. I know what data type will be passed to me by means of an associated value. For example, below is what my function looks like:

```
void * (int type, void * data);
```

If the void pointer I am passed was originally a char type, and I cast it back to a char type, is there a way of determining how many bytes are associated with that pointer? For example, if my function is called as follows:

```
f(1, (void *)"Hello world");
```

and I cast the void pointer back to a char pointer

```
char * p = (char *)data;
```

Is there some way I can figure out how many bytes were used? Would I possibly have to search for the null character and count how many bytes away it is from the original pointer? What would I have to do to find the size of the int and float as well?

Comment: you need a 3r argument, or document a terminatror value for int and float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I possibly have to search for the null character and count how
>   many bytes away it is from the original pointer?

Yes, if your `void*` is actually a `char*` this will work.

> What would I have to do to find the size of the int and float as well?

`int` and `float` as always the same size (it depends from your architecture, generally 32 or 64 bit. Use `sizeof` operator to determine the exact size). If you are passing an array of int as `void*` you haven't any way to find its length.

Generally in these cases it's convinent to pass the size to your function too.

Comment: Ahh, I completely ignored the fact that int's and float's are a specific size... If it were possible for me to send the size, I would prefer to do that over what I am doing now. ha. Thanks.

Comment: "int and float as always the same size" NOT!!!! int can be 16bit, float not less than 32 (all intel 16 systems)